# Alternative form for sinh(x)/cosh(x) .

Tags: numerical-methods

I have the following expression.
$$
\tanh (x) = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}
$$
I know that they derive one from another , but how do I rewrite them in alternative forms in order to not get a NaN(not a number) when will be evaluating for big values.
I get NaN for the last 2 formulas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For large positive $x$ rewrite the formula as
$$
\tanh (x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}= \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}} = \frac{1 - e^{-2x}}{1 + e^{-2x}}\cdot
$$
The last fraction can be evaluated without overflow. For negative $x$ use $\tanh(-x)=-\tanh(x).$

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: That avoids the $\infty/\infty$ problem, but $x$ doesn't have to be particularly large before the floating-point result collapses to $1$ anyway. Perhaps what's really needed in the large-$x$ case is a numerically robust way to compute $1-\tanh x$ instead?

Comment: Actually in my problem is said that I have to evaluate the function for big values(i.e. 1000)and to observe that I'm not getting a number.So I have to find another way to compute this function and be precise as possible.

Comment: @rhauder: If you're representing the result as an IEEE double, you might as well compute it as the constant `1.0` if $x$ is greater than about $40$. It will be closer to that than to the largest representable number less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Gammatester's solution avoids the $\infty/\infty$ problem, but $x$ doesn't have to be particularly large before the true result would round to `1.0` in machine floating point anyway.

In case you need the difference between $\tanh x$ and $1$ in your application, it would probably be beneficial to switch to something like
$$ 1 - \tanh x = \frac{2}{e^{2x}+1} $$
when $x$ is larger than about $1$.

Comment: But this will overflow again in this simple form.

Comment: @gammatester: If $e^{2x}$ overflows a double, then the true value of $1-\tanh x$ would underflow to `0.0` anyway -- and that is exactly what machine arithmetic would produce here too, since $2/\infty=0$. (This happens around $x=700$, give or take a few).

Comment: No it is better to write $$ 1 - \tanh x = \frac{2e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}$$ to get the complete asymptotic form of  $1 - \tanh x.$

Comment: @gammatester: Why? To get denormals?

Comment: That depends on the machine/language/compiler: If the default action is overflow=exception and underflow=flush-to-zero, it is better to use the second form.